# PetaPoco db.SingleOrDefault<T> passing in where name as well as value

Tags: petapoco

I am trying to write a generic method to call DB records.

All works except to make the method useful I need to passing the WHERE name value too...as well as the value to match.

Something like this...

```
T values = db.SingleOrDefault<T>("WHERE " + name + " = @0", value);
```

This works but its a bit of a clunk!

```
    string sql = "WHERE " + name + " = @0";
    T values = db.SingleOrDefault<T>(sql, value);
```

Can this be done with different syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to hide the syntax if that bothers you

```
    public static T SingleOrDefaultWithWhere<T>(this PetaPoco.Database db, string name, object value) {
        string sql = "WHERE " + name + " = @0";
        return db.SingleOrDefault<T>(sql, value);
    }
```

And then just call

```
T values = db.SingleOrDefaultWithWhere<T>(name, value);
```